# I am facing two problems. this code supposed to print the 'to do' list

Tags: javascript

first problem is I have to type 'q' or 'quit' over 2 times to get the console.log("OK! You have quitted the app ") printed in console. Other one is I can not see the todo list printed when I type 'list' until I quit that means I type 'q' or 'quit'. please can anyone solve these problem?

```js
let input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
const toDo = ['Visit Resham', 'Check progress of Barth certificate'];

while (input !== 'quit' && input !== 'q') {

  if (input === 'list') {
    prompt("List has been printed! ")
    console.log('******************')

    for (let i = 0; i < toDo.length; i++) {
      console.log(`${i} : ${toDo[i]}`);
    }

    console.log('*****************')
  }
  input = prompt("What would you like to do?")
}
console.log("OK! You have quitted the app ")
```

Comment: Try running the code manually/by hand.

Comment: `prompt("List has been printed! ")` waits for input and then throws away what you enter.  Did you mean `alert`?

Comment: I see the list in the console after I answer the "List has ben printed" prompt.

Comment: It doesn't show right away in the Stack Snippet console because of the way that's implemented with DOM methods. But it shows immediately in the real console.

Comment: Thanks :) I meant to use 'alert' there. prompt was causing all the problem

Comment: It's because after printing the list, you create a new prompt with "List printed". Then at the end you create another new prompt. So now you have 2 overlapping prompts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prompt the user in your if statement, which could be replaced with an alert instead... but if you want to keep it, simply put the prompt outside of the if inside an else.

```js
let input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
const toDo = ['Visit Resham', 'Check progress of Barth certificate'];

while (input !== 'quit' && input !== 'q') {

  if (input === 'list') {
    //alert("List has been printed! ")
    input = prompt("List has been printed! ")
    console.log('******************')

    for (let i = 0; i < toDo.length; i++) {
      console.log(`${i} : ${toDo[i]}`);
    }

    console.log('*****************')
  }
  else
  {
    input = prompt("What would you like to do?")
  }
}
console.log("OK! You have quitted the app ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your code a little and hope it will work now.

```js
let input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
const toDo = ["Visit Resham", "Check progress of Barth certificate"];

while (input !== "quit" && input !== "q") {
  if (input === "list") {
    console.log("******************");

    for (let i = 0; i < toDo.length; i++) {
      console.log(`${i} : ${toDo[i]}`);
    }

    console.log("*****************");
    alert("List has been printed! ");
  }
  input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
}
console.log("OK! You have quitted the app ");
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works :) I used prompt instead of using alert